# Is there a way to evaluate a variable in vba?

Tags: ms-access, variables, vba

I have a variable newItem. I want to place the value stored in newItem into a string. I thought I would be able to accomplish this with...

```
myString = eval(newItem)
```

...but it doesn't work.

Is there any way to evaluate a variable in Access vba?

Comment: In what way does it not work? Can you post the error and/or aberrant behaviour you see when you try to do this? Thanks

Comment: If I enter ?eval ("newItem") in the immediate window, I get the following error: "MS Access can't find the name 'newItem' you entered in the expression. Without quotes around "newItem" it says there is invalid syntax.

Comment: If this is a follow on from your previous post, I suspect that you need to replace NewItem in your string with the value of newitem using the Replace function. I still have doubts about the way you are approaching this problem.

Comment: @JackOrangeLantern you might like to read some of the guidelines on meta for editing. For example, you have been adding tags to titles and this is discoureaged: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70498/automatic-removal-of-bracketed-tags-from-question-titles Also, please do not remove main tags from the tag list.

Comment: @Remou Thank you for the links; I should have consulted these guidelines before editing. I will strictly adhere to these guidelines in the future when editing posts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Eval` is a function that will execute the text in the given string as if it were code.

I think what you are looking for is CInt:

```
Dim s as String : s = "15"
Dim i as Integer : i = CInt(s)
'at this point, i = 15, and s = "15"
```

Similarly, you should look into CStr, CLng, CDate, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Sure is. you need to typecast the variable to a string.

In VBA you use `myString = CStr(var)`

I believe these are all the typecasts in vba:

```
CBool(expression)
CByte(expression)
CCur(expression)
CDate(expression)
CDbl(expression)
CDec(expression)
CInt(expression)
CLng(expression)
CSng(expression)
CVar(expression)
CStr(expression)
```

Answer (score 1):

**[You can use the Script Control for that too :)](http://sarfraznawaz.wordpress.com/2010/02/28/creating-advanced-calculator-with-4-lines-of-code/)**